# Could the directus app be used in a django stack as a CMS

Tags: django, directus

I am developing a web application in django and react but would like to use directus as a cms. I already have a mysql database and RESTful api set up and working so I was wondering if I could use the directus application as an application within django to manage and update content?

if not what would be the correct way to connect directus to my application? or should I stick with a cms built for integration into django projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SDK for django/python yet but you can still use the standard way of HTTP requests instead.

In the docs, you can learn more about how to authenticate and how to make requests or update data.

Docs: https://docs.directus.io/api/reference.html#authentication